# There is a way to enable a visual line on VS Code to show the limit for PEP8?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pep8

I want to see a vertical line on my VS Code editor. There's a way to show It? How do I enable this?

I've already installed pylint and pep8. It seems to working fine. I just want to see the line in my editor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest way is to use the "editor.rulers" setting.

settings.json:

```
{
  "[python]": {
    "editor.rulers": [100]
  }
}
```